# How to use Regex with numbers

Tags: node.js, regex, regexp-substr

I am new to programming and building my first full stack application. In my application I have two entities, Branches and Accounts. Branches names are alphanumerical strings whereas the Accounts are just numbers for example 116003183, 16582368. The scenario is that when a user types in a first few letters of the Branch all the matching results show up. I am unable to do the same with Accounts as that is all numbers. I looked up on few sites that you can use [0-9] but I can't figure out how would I implement that code. Here's my code. Any Help or leads would be appreciated.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
let query = Account.find()
if (req.query.name != null && req.query.name != ''){
query= query.regex('name',new RegExp(req.query.name))
    }  
 try{
 const accounts = await query.exec()
 res.render('accounts/index',{
 accounts: accounts,
 searchOptions:req.query
 })
 }
 catch(err) {

 res.redirect('/')
  }        
  })
```

Comment: Just to be clear .. `name` in the `Account` entity is of type `number` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `$expr`-[operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), you can build a query that converts the account name field of type `number` to a string and then do a regex match on that field:

```
// ...
const query = {};
if (req.query.name != null && req.query.name != ''){
   query.$expr = {
        "$regexMatch": {
           "input": {"$toString": "$name"}, 
           "regex": new RegExp(req.query.name)
        }
    }
}
const accounts = await Account.find(query);
// ...
```